# Import RTF in web application

Tags: c#, html, .net, import, rtf

I am creating asp.net web application. In that i have functionality to add data in ckeditor. So i get data in html format. And our data is already ready in word file which i have to import in our database. The data is in gujarati and with special characters and images. To import word file, i have created one desktop utility which have rtf control and try to insert record in database. in this utility i have added rtf control then read word document line by line and paste it into a rtf and at last i insert rtf text in database.

Now the issue is when i insert text from rtf, it removes all images and special characters. It is a  problem. So either i have convert rtf to html or i have to support rtf in web application. but i am not finding solution from any of above.

So looking for any solution to import rtf data with gujarati fonts, images and special character.

Comment: Please be more specific: do you mean you lose images and special characters after DB insert? I mean, the DB contains malformed data ? What is the DB engine ? Without those details I can point you e.g. to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996460/inserting-gujarati-text-into-a-mysql-tables-results-in-junk-characters-and-unrea

Comment: I am using rtf text instead of rtf because we have to display it in web application as html. and text does not provide image and special characters in it. And i am using sql server 2005 as database and i need to show text which we are importing into a asp.net web applicaiton.

Comment: I do not know if this will help you but check out those links: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/869cfa5e-7994-4d75-a15a-04dca21743d6/how-to-reconstruct-a-rtf-file-from-image-datatype-in-ms-sql-2000, http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e, http://sqlmag.com/development/store-rtf-data-sql-server-database, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152424/parse-display-rtf-text-in-html